# Error while calculating discount using CLIPS rule engine

Tags: clips

i am new to clips rule engine and have to do following in clips in mobile app.
if a person buys x amount of product A give him y discount.

Following is the code i have written to first check if my productid is in orders.

```
(deftemplate Producttemp
(slot productid (type INTEGER))
(slot umid)
(slot quantity (type INTEGER))
)

(deffacts orders
(Producttemp (productid 123) (umid CG) (quantity 4))
(Producttemp (productid 456) (umid CG) (quantity 2))
)



(defrule checkorder
=>
 (printout t "Enter the productid: ")
  (bind ?p1 (readline))
   (printout t "Enter another quantity: ")
   (bind ?p2 (readline))

   (do-for-all-facts ((?o Producttemp)) 
       (and (eq ?p1 ?o:p1)
            (eq ?p2 ?o:p2))
       (printout t ?p1 " is a " ?o: productid" in order " ?p2 crlf)))
)
```

I am getting following error.

```
Defining defrule: checkorder 
[PRCCODE3] Undefined variable o: referenced in RHS of defrule.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a space between **?o:** and **product** in the last printout statement. There's also an extraneous right parenthesis at the end of the rule. This rule will load without any syntax errors:

```
(defrule checkorder
   =>
   (printout t "Enter the productid: ")
   (bind ?p1 (readline))
   (printout t "Enter another quantity: ")
   (bind ?p2 (readline))

   (do-for-all-facts ((?o Producttemp)) 
       (and (eq ?p1 ?o:p1)
            (eq ?p2 ?o:p2))
       (printout t ?p1 " is a " ?o:productid" in order " ?p2 crlf))
)
```

There are two other issues with your rule. Within the fact query you reference the **p1** and **p2** slots of the **Producttemp** fact with the references **?o:p1** and **?o:p2**, but these slots do not exist. Perhaps you intend the **productid** and **quantity** slots. You also use the **readline** function to get input. This will return a string, but your fact slots contain symbols and integers, not strings, so any comparisons between these values using the **eq** function will fail since the types are not the same. You should use the **read** function instead.